# Shopify related products via tag instead of collection

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a "***Related Products***" section on my Product page. Right now it shows products that a related by "***collection***". Is it possible to show related products that have the same tag?

This is my ***related-products.liquid*** code.

Thanks.

```
{% if section.settings.show_related_products == true %}
<hr>
<div class="product-template__container page-width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="ProductSection-{{ section.id }}" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="product" data-enable-history-state="true">



{% comment %}
  Number of related items per row,
  and number of rows.
{% endcomment %}

{% assign number_of_related_products_per_row = section.settings.related_grid_num %}
{% assign number_of_rows = section.settings.related_grid_row %}

{% comment %}
  Heading.
  Leave blank if you don't need one.
{% endcomment %}

{% assign heading = section.settings.related_title %}

{% comment %}
  Set either or both to true, if you want
  to limit yourself to items with same vendor, and/or type.
{% endcomment %}

{% assign same_vendor = false %}
{% assign same_type = false %}

{% comment %}
  Collections to ignore.
  Never pick related items from those.
{% endcomment %}

{% assign exclusions = 'frontpage,all' | split: ',' %}

{% comment %}
  Looking for a relevant collection.
{% endcomment %}

{% if product.metafields.c_f['Related Products'] %}
  {% assign collection = collections[product.metafields.c_f['Related Products']] %}
{% endif %}

{% assign found_a_collection = false %}
{% if collection and collection.all_products_count > 1 %}
  {% unless exclusions contains collection.handle %}
    {% assign found_a_collection = true %}
  {% endunless %}
{% endif %}
{% unless found_a_collection %}
  {% for c in product.collections %}
    {% unless exclusions contains c.handle or c.all_products_count < 2 %}
      {% assign found_a_collection = true %}
      {% assign collection = c %}
      {% break %}
    {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endunless %}

{% comment %}
  If we have a relevant collection.
{% endcomment %}

{% if found_a_collection %}

  {% assign counter = 0 %}
  {% assign break_at = number_of_rows | times: number_of_related_products_per_row %}
  {% assign current_product = product %}

  {% case number_of_related_products_per_row %}
    {% when '1' %}
      {% assign grid_item_width = '' %}
  {%- assign max_height = 700 -%}
    {% when '2' %}
      {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-half' %}
      {%- assign max_height = 530 -%}
    {% when '3' %}
      {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-third' %}
      {%- assign max_height = 345 -%}
    {% when '4' %}
      {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter' %}
  {%- assign max_height = 250 -%}
    {% when '5' %}
      {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-fifth' %}
  {%- assign max_height = 195 -%}
    {% when '6' %}
      {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-sixth' %}
  {%- assign max_height = 195 -%}
    {% else %}
      {% assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter' %}
  {%- assign max_height = 195 -%}
  {% endcase %}


  {% capture related_items %}
<div class="grid grid--uniform{% if collection.products_count > 0 %} grid--view-items{% endif %}">

  {% for product in collection.products %}
  {% unless product.handle == current_product.handle %}
  {% unless same_vendor and current_product.vendor != product.vendor %}
  {% unless same_type and current_product.type != product.type %}
  <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }}">
    {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: max_height %}
  </div>
  {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
  {% if counter == break_at %}
  {% break %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endunless %}
  {% endunless %}
  {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
  {% endcapture %}

  {% assign related_items = related_items | trim %}

  {% unless related_items == blank %}

  <aside class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      {% unless heading == blank %}
      <header class="section-header">
        <h2 class="section-header__title">{{ heading }}</h2>
      </header>
      {% endunless %}
      <div class="grid-uniform">
        {{ related_items }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>

  {% endunless %}

{% endif %}

</div>
{% endif %}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Related products",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_related_products",
      "label": "Show related products",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "id": "related_title",
      "type": "text",
      "label": "Section title",
      "default": "Other fine products"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "related_grid_num",
      "label": "Products per row (Desktop)",
      "default": "4",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "2",
          "label": "2"
        },
        {
          "value": "3",
          "label": "3"
        },
        {
          "value": "4",
          "label": "4"
        },
        {
          "value": "5",
          "label": "5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "related_grid_row",
      "label": "Number of rows (Desktop)",
      "default": "1",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "1",
          "label": "1"
        },
        {
          "value": "2",
          "label": "2"
        },
        {
          "value": "3",
          "label": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to related section by tags it's very limited if you use liquid logic by itself.

Why is that? Because you are limited by 50 products per request and if none of those products have your tag you are pretty much screwed since no products will be shown.

The best approach will be to use JavaScript and load the post via AJAX. Why? Because you can access the tagged page directly and append the number of post you like to show at the section.

So here are the two options.

1) Only liquid ( not the best approach )

```
{% assign currentTags = product.tags %}
{% assign limit = 4 %}
{% assign count = 0 %}
{% for related in collection.products %}
    {% for tag in related.tags %}
        {% if currentTags contains tag and count < limit %}
            {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}
            SHOW PRODUCT INFO HERE
        {% endif %}
        {% if count >= limit %}
            {% break %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if count >= limit %}
        {% break %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

2) Using JavaScript:

```
{% assign currentTag = product.tags[0] %} // Some logic for the tag you like to show
<div class="related-products"></div>
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '{{ shop.url }}/collections/all/{{ currentTag }}',
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        jQuery('.related-products').append($(data).find('.product-item'));
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm newbie in liquid where should I put your code?